# aptana studio 3 ignore error once

Tags: aptana

```
Recently I use python sqlalchemy in aptana studio 3,
```

And the code:

```
 wxf = session.query(User).\
               options(subqueryload(User.addresses)).\
               filter_by(name='xf').one()
```

is right,but aptana pydev show the wavy line below the word "User.addresses" 
thought the code can run, but I want to kill the wavy line.
how to ignore the error once in the aptana.